# When connecting (winsock2) socket i get error 10038

Tags: c, sockets, networking, tcp, winsock2

**Hello**, i'm coding a client with sockets (i usually do that in unix but i wanted to try in windows) with the **winsock2** library. When i'm connecting the socket to an ip i get error 10038. I googled **msdn** and i found out that i'm doing a socket action on a non-socket. Which if i'm correct means that i'm not creating the socket or *"binding"* the address and ports to the socket in the right way. Tried my best but can't find any errors in my code. **Thanks in advance.**

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>





#define okay(msg, ...) printf("[+] " msg "\n", ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define info(msg, ...) printf("[!] " msg "\n", ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define error(msg, ...) printf("[-] " msg "\n", ##__VA_ARGS__)


int main() {

    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET cs;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    char* ip = "127.0.0.1";
    int port = 4444;


    info("Initializing socket...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0) {
        error("Couldn't initialize socket. Error -> %d", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    okay("Succesfully initialized socket.");

    info("Creating socket...");
    if (cs = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        error("Couldn't create socket. Error -> %d", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    okay("Succesfully created socket.");

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    InetPton(AF_INET, ip, &addr.sin_addr.s_addr);
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);

    //info("IP -> %d", addr.sin_addr.s_addr);
    //info("PORT -> %d", addr.sin_port);

    info("Connecting to -> %s:%d", ip, port);
    if (connect(cs, (SOCKADDR *) &addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0) {
        error("Couldn't connect to %s:%d, error -> %d", ip, port, WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    okay("Connected to %s:%d", ip, port);

    char* msg = "lol";

    int response = send(cs, msg, strlen(msg), 0);

    if(response == SOCKET_ERROR){
        error("Couldn't send message to %s:%d", ip, port);
        info("Closing socket...");
        WSACleanup();
        okay("Succesfully closed socket.");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    okay("Succesfully sent %d bytes to %s:%d", response, ip, port);

    info("Closing socket...");
    WSACleanup();
    okay("Succesfully closed socket.");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: "Which if i'm correct means that i'm not creating the socket": yes. "... or "binding" the address and ports to the socket in the right way.": no. `if (cs = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) == INVALID_SOCKET)` should be `if ((cs = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET) `.

Comment: lmao how did my editor not flag that stupid error ._. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Because there's nothing wrong with it syntactically. The stupid error is yours. The code you wrote assigned the result of `==` to `cs`, i.e. `true` or `false`. The code you intended assigns the result of `socket()` to `cs` and compares that to `INVALID_SOCKET`. The editor can't read your mind.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the connect() call, but rather in how you store the return value of socket().

```
 if (cs = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) == INVALID_SOCKET)
```

This does not store the return value of socket() into cs and compare it to INVALID_SOCKET, but rather compares the return value of socket() with INVALID_SOCKET and stores the result of that comparison into cs.
This means that, on successful calls, the result is 0 (since the socket is not invalid), and on error it is 1. These values *might* be valid sockets, but in all likelihood they are not the socket you created.

To solve it, you can either add parentheses or divide the line into two, like so:

```
// Add parentheses
if ((cs = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET) {
...
```

or

```
// Divide the operation into two lines
cs = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(cs == INVALID_SOCKET) {
...
```